# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0" only on Chrome - why?

Tags: angularjs, json

I discovered a strange error today that only appears when loading:
localhost:9000 and only on Chrome!
AND http://parke.linkpc.net:9000/ works fine on Chrome!
AND localhost:9000 works fine on Firefox.
I went back many builds and still see the same, so this has something to do with the hostname not specified?  Note I have cleared chrome cache etc. but no help.

This happens when by 'Auth' service is being instantiated and calling:

```
$cookieStore.get('token'))
```

which calls:

```
$cookieStore.get('token'))
```

and then when it is attempting to parse a cookie at the code:

```
 getObject: function(key) {
      var value = this.get(key);
      return value ? angular.fromJson(value) : value;
    },
```

value: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NzY5ODI5Y2MyZjU5NGM0NWQwNjMxODkiLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjY1MzI1NDAsImV4cCI6MTQ2NjU1MDU0MH0.Vm9GtPMxts1915J6UIzQtDDJ8LvXUKcbWrRxT8jQWzk"

It crashes with:

```
"Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0"
```

Why is this?  And why only on Chrome?

NEXT: I deleted all the cookies and the problem went away.  And I cannot generate it a second time.  So go figure....   But it would be nice to know what could cause this issue!

Answer (score -1):

Change the name of key 'token'.

Example:

```
$cookieStore.get('authKey'))
```

Instead of:

```
$cookieStore.get('token'))
```

Comment: is a token a reserved name? may be